# How do I pass props in react router v4?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I need to pass some data in `Link` component of `react router v4`, but I cannot find a way to do it.

Basically, I have some links that are dynamically generated. I have linked these links with `Link` component in the following way. Upon clicking one of these links, user is routed to a new component. I want to pass some data into these new component so that I can display them there.

```
<Link to="dynamic link here">some text</Link>
```

Is there some sort of `<Link to="path" data="data here">some text</Link>` method in `react router v4`? I cannot seem to find it in the documentation page.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass an object as the `to` prop and specify `state`. See the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object).

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/courses',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}}> Courses </Link>
```

Then you can grab that state in the new route from `this.props.location.state`

Comment: This is weird. It worked the first time and after I changed pathname to a variable, it does not work anymore even after I changed the pathname back to a static route without the variable.

Comment: I tried with closing the ```Link``` component instead of self-closing itself and it works again. So instead of ```<Link to={{pathname: '/courses', state : {some data} }}/>```, I did ```<Link to={{pathname: '/courses', state : {some data} }}>some text</Link>```.